In the DDPG algorithm, is it always necessary to normalize the reward values?
How can we determine the best scale for reward values in the DDPG algorithm, and is normalization necessary?
If the reward does not have a maximum value, what is the best method to normalize it?
My code addresses a wireless communication problem where the reward function represents the network delay.
I would appreciate it if you could guide me.

"My code addresses" - You forgot to add said code

"If the reward does not have a maximum value" suggests that you are only looking into Min/Max scaling, but there are other methods too (for example Z score). Nevertheless, these are mostly theoretical questions, not a debugging issue, so they may not be appropriate for StackOverflow. This question seems more appropriate for (probably) AI, Data Science or Cross Validated sites.
